Antiforgery token error in Blazor Server with Minimal API
I have a .NET 8 Blazor Server which serves html pages. In addition to that I wanted to add few Minimal API endpoints. Whenever I try to send request to endpoints I recieve "A valid antiforgery token was not provided with the request. Add an antiforgery token, or disable antiforgery validation
for this endpoint." response.
I would like to keep HTML pages protected but disable protection for the API.
I found that MinimalApi has extension method for disabling antiforgery – DisableAntiforgery().
I tried to call it on the Endpoint Group, where my EPs are located and I also called that directly on the Minimal EP. Both with no success.
var apiGroup = app.MapGroup("api/auth")
    .DisableAntiforgery();

apiGroup.MapGet("google", (Guid requestId, IGoogleAuthService authService) =>
{
    // ...
})
.DisableAntiforgery();

For my Program.cs configuration:
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.AddApplicationEndpoints(); // I add custom EPs here

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery(); // Antiforgery is enabled here

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


I tested the antiforgery in a new Blazor web app with server render mode .net8 but cannot reproduce your problem. With your code I send a simple request and it works as expected. Is it a new app or migrated, or could you please provide more details?

@FengzhiZhou
It is a newly created App. I make complex testing myself trying to go step by step followed by validation process and i figured out that the problem was in the wrong route name in the user agent (Postman).
Whenever i try to send request to nonexistent route I would expect that it results 404. Not 400 with "A valid antiforgery token was not provided with the request. Add an antiforgery token, or disable antiforgery validation
for this endpoint." message.
example call that results to this message:
POST .../api/auth/google/x

I tested with several ways but still cannot reproduce it , the same url gets a code of 404 . It might results from some other issues not shown in your snippets . I find some documents relating to the antiforgery , you could refer to them and find some explanations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-support  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-support
